# 'Error: no valid set of coefficients has been found: please supply starting values' when fitting svyglm binomial('identity') for risk difference

Tags: r, glm, survey

I was trying to fit a glm from the binomial family with identity link to survey weighted data to calculate the risk difference. I was able to run the svyglm model with starting values, however when I tried to extract asymmetric confidence intervals using the likelihood method I received the above error.

Sample data of the first 4 entries using dput:

```
> data <- structure(list(binary_outcome= structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    binary_exposure= structure(c(1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 2L, NA), .Label = c("1", "2"), label = "binary exposure", class = "factor"), 
    wt = c(191217, 89001, 16578, 188901, 7787, 7787, 3876, 
    27569, 7208, 7208, 8594, 170173, 3430, 7208, 53034, 53034, 
    5037, 5037, 786465, 177210, 7849, 9038, 6353, 3837, 89733, 
    188973, 176366, 188736, 3456, 27478), block = c("a", 
    "a", "b", "c", "w", "e", 
    "j", "c", "g", "r", "j", 
    "r", "v", "f", "g", "d", 
    "a", "a", "v", "t", "l", 
    "q", "d", "n", 
    "m", "b", "g", "k", "m", 
    "g"), strata_study = c("C R", "K U", 
    "TN R", "WB R", "K R", "K R", 
    "TN U", "WB U", "TN U", "TN U", 
    "O U", "M U", "K U", "TN U", 
    "WB U", "WB U", "K R", "K R", 
    "D U", "WB R", "TN U", "TN U", 
    "TN U", "K U", "D U", "WB R", "C R", 
    "WB R", "K U", "WB U")), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -30L), groups = structure(list(
    binary_outcome = structure(1:2, .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    .rows = structure(list(1:15, 16:30), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

I ran the following to fit the svyglm model to estimate the risk difference:

```
> svy_design <- svydesign(ids = ~block, strata = ~strata_study, weights = ~wt, data = data, nest = TRUE, fpc = NULL)

> summary(svyglm(I(binary_outcome==1)~binary_exposure, design=svy_design,family=quasi(link="identity",variance="mu(1-mu)"),  start=c(0.1,0.6)))
```

This gives the following result:

```
Call:
svyglm(formula = I(binary_outcome == 1) ~ binary_exposure, design = svy_design, 
    family = quasi(link = "identity", variance = "mu(1-mu)"), 
    start = c(0.1, 0.1))

Survey design:
svydesign(ids = ~block, strata = ~strata_study, weights = ~wt, 
    data = data, nest = TRUE, fpc = NULL)

Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)        0.3575     0.2043   1.750   0.1107  
binary_exposure2   0.6425     0.2043   3.145   0.0104 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for quasi family taken to be 0.7467369)

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2
```

However, I would like to generate the confidence intervals using likelihood method so I ran the following:

```
> confint(svyglm(I(binary_outcome==1)~binary_exposure, design=svy_design,family=quasi(link="identity",variance="mu(1-mu)"),  start=c(0.1,0.6)), method="likelihood")
```

And recevied the following error message:

```
Error: no valid set of coefficients has been found: please supply starting values
```

Any help on this would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the above with some data using dput. I hope its sufficient.

Comment: The data you gave is insufficient to fit to svyglm. It would be helpful to have minimal data to reproduce your code. I get this error upon running `svyglm()` - 
```Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels```

Comment: @PrashantBharadwaj thanks for the reply! I have added a minimal dataset with updated code and results. Hope this is better. I am getting the same error message I had with my original dataset - unfortunetly I can't share it on here yet. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it answers your question, but using the `confint` without the `method="likelihood"` parameter gives an output.
Sorry I'm not very knowledgeable about the stats behind this to confirm if the result is the same..

```r
data <- structure(list(binary_outcome= structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
                       binary_exposure= structure(c(1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 
                                                    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 
                                                    NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 2L, NA), .Label = c("1", "2"), label = "binary exposure", class = "factor"), 
                       wt = c(191217, 89001, 16578, 188901, 7787, 7787, 3876, 
                              27569, 7208, 7208, 8594, 170173, 3430, 7208, 53034, 53034, 
                              5037, 5037, 786465, 177210, 7849, 9038, 6353, 3837, 89733, 
                              188973, 176366, 188736, 3456, 27478), block = c("a", 
                                                                              "a", "b", "c", "w", "e", 
                                                                              "j", "c", "g", "r", "j", 
                                                                              "r", "v", "f", "g", "d", 
                                                                              "a", "a", "v", "t", "l", 
                                                                              "q", "d", "n", 
                                                                              "m", "b", "g", "k", "m", 
                                                                              "g"), strata_study = c("C R", "K U", 
                                                                                                     "TN R", "WB R", "K R", "K R", 
                                                                                                     "TN U", "WB U", "TN U", "TN U", 
                                                                                                     "O U", "M U", "K U", "TN U", 
                                                                                                     "WB U", "WB U", "K R", "K R", 
                                                                                                     "D U", "WB R", "TN U", "TN U", 
                                                                                                     "TN U", "K U", "D U", "WB R", "C R", 
                                                                                                     "WB R", "K U", "WB U")), class = c("grouped_df", 
                                                                                                                                        "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -30L), groups = structure(list(
                                                                                                                                          binary_outcome = structure(1:2, .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
                                                                                                                                          .rows = structure(list(1:15, 16:30), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                            "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
# clean up data : (to prevent error with svyglm)
dat2 <- dplyr::filter(data, !stringr::str_detect(strata_study, 'M U|O U|TN R')) # remove strata with only one incidence

# surveydesign
svy_design <- survey::svydesign(ids = ~block, strata = ~strata_study, weights = ~wt, data = dat2, nest = TRUE, fpc = NULL)

# run glm fit
svyfit <- survey::svyglm(I(binary_outcome==1)~binary_exposure, design=svy_design,family=quasi(link="identity",variance="mu(1-mu)"),  start=c(0.1,0.6))
#> Warning: step size truncated: out of bounds

#> Warning: step size truncated: out of bounds

#> Warning: step size truncated: out of bounds

#> Warning: step size truncated: out of bounds

#> Warning: step size truncated: out of bounds

#> Warning: step size truncated: out of bounds

#> Warning: step size truncated: out of bounds

#> Warning: step size truncated: out of bounds

#> Warning: step size truncated: out of bounds
#> Warning: glm.fit: algorithm stopped at boundary value

# summarize
summary(svyfit)
#> 
#> Call:
#> svyglm(formula = I(binary_outcome == 1) ~ binary_exposure, design = svy_design, 
#>     family = quasi(link = "identity", variance = "mu(1-mu)"), 
#>     start = c(0.1, 0.6))
#> 
#> Survey design:
#> survey::svydesign(ids = ~block, strata = ~strata_study, weights = ~wt, 
#>     data = dat2, nest = TRUE, fpc = NULL)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
#> (Intercept)        0.4206     0.2410   1.745    0.112  
#> binary_exposure2   0.5794     0.2410   2.404    0.037 *
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> (Dispersion parameter for quasi family taken to be 0.6920658)
#> 
#> Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 10

# confidence interval
confint(svyfit)
#>                        2.5 %    97.5 %
#> (Intercept)      -0.11633493 0.9575489
#> binary_exposure2  0.04245107 1.1163349
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>